# Search within XML with PHP code

Tags: php, xml, xpath

this is my code and i am trying to show the value of xml using Xpath but when i run this i am getting error in my code.

Here is the code

```
<?php
$load = new DOMDocument();
$load = simplexml_load_file("testing.xml");
var_dump($load);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($load);
var_dump($xpath);
$path1 = "/clip/metadata[name=keywords]/value";
$query = $xpath->query($path1);
var_dump("$query"); 
?>
```

this is the error, which i am getting

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMXPath::__construct() must be an instance of DOMDocument, instance of SimpleXMLElement given in C:\xampp\htdocs\xml-text\index.php on line 5
```

Comment: No need to use `simplexml_load_file`, instead you can use [load](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) method of the `DOMDocument` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the error, you are passing a `SimpleXmlElement` object instead of a `DOMDocument` object.

My previous answer was incorrect. It showed how to convert a `SimpleXmlElement` to a `DOMElement` not a `DOMDocument`.

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php is how to properly load an xml file into a `DOMDocument` object.

```
$load = new DOMDocument();
$load->load("testing.xml");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($load);
```

Specifically to get the value of the  node with the name Keywords you would do something like this

```
$load = new DOMDocument();
$load->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$load->load(__DIR__ . "/testing.xml");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($load);
$path1 = '//clip/metadata/name[ . = "Keywords"]';
$query = $xpath->query($path1);
foreach($query as $entry) {
    $value = $entry->parentNode->childNodes->item(1)->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMXPath::__construct() must be an instance of DOMDocument, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\xml-text\index.php on line 6`

Comment: thanks @ honerlawd 
now i am having this error to just to let you know, i am also trying to get it away and reading from the Link , what you have posted

Comment: @kunal I fixed my answer. I realized I was converting from `SimpleXmlElement` to `DOMElement` not `DOMDocument`.

Comment: thanks @honerlawd i seen your change and implementing it.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<clip>
<supplier>people</supplier>
  <metadata>
    <name>Owner</name>
    <value>Self-Company</value>
  </metadata>
  <metadata>
    <name>Keywords</name>
    <value>school: teacher, student classes</value>
  </metadata>
  </clip>`

Comment: this is my xml
your answer has helped me so far but just need your little help again, i am trying to show the value of keyword and with my code i am receivng this value `object(DOMNodeList)#3 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) } `

Comment: @kunal I will add the solution to my solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot Man!! I get what i was looking to Do!

i have leveled it Up and Marked as helped me your solution really helped me.

Comment: as i will will have 15 points , will make level Up to your answer!!

Comment: hi @honerlawd,
 
i am running with another Problem.

`<?php
 $dir = 'xml';
$files = scandir($dir, 1);
//var_dump($files);
foreach ($files as $xml)
{
$load = new DOMDocument();

$load->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$load->load($xml);
var_dump($load); die();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($load);
$path1 = '//clip/metadata/name[ . = "Keywords"] | //clip/metadata/name[ . = "TE.OriginalName"]';
$query = $xpath->query($path1);
foreach($query as $entry) {
    $value = $entry->parentNode->childNodes->item(1)->nodeValue;
 var_dump($value);
}
}
?>`

this is my code and i am having this error.

Comment: `Warning: DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/xml-text/testing1.xml" in C:\xampp\htdocs\xml-text\index.php on line 11`

Answer (score 2):

As the error states, you are not passing the constructor the appropriate arguments. `simplexml_load_file` returns a `SimpleXmlElement` object, NOT a `DOMDocument` object.

Comment: thanks @thatidiotguy i  am totally New with XML Programming through PHP and I am trying to  load an xml file and then search within it.
can you please give me a tip ,what can i used here.
i also have used `loadXML();` function but it still didnt work